# Error en Ubuntu: PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_mbstring.dll' - cannot open shared object file

Tags: php

Cuando inento instalar Laravel en Ubuntu sale esa información, he inserido el siguiente comando para realizar la instalacion:

```
sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel
```

OJO: Tengo el PHP 7.1 instalado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba reinstalando la extensión `php-mbstring`,

`sudo apt-get install php-mbstring`

Luego la desactivas y activas nuevamente usando `phpenmod/phpdismod`

`sudo phpdismod mbstring # disable mbstring extension
 sudo phpenmod mbstring # enable mbstring extension again`

En el caso de que este usando windows, que no recomiendo, deberas sacar la habilitar esta extensión en el archivo de configuración `.ini`

Espero pueda ayudar,

Comment: Sí perfecto, hasta ahí todo bien, pero cuando instalo el Laravel ya en mi sistema me genera otro error, la pantalla aparece en blanco cuando ingreso al public/index de mi proyecto laravel :(

Comment: Entonces ese es otro problema. Habilita los errores para poder obtener el problema. Saludos

Comment: @jolsalazar podrías ayudarme con otras librerias que generan el mismo error? `/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_pgsql.dll`, `php_pdo_pgsql.dll`

Comment: @CesarRomero tienes la libretia pgsql instalada? `apt-get install php-pgsql` ? recuerda que debes instalar lo requerido para laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation#server-requirements

Comment: Gracias @jolsalazar tuve algunos problemas al cambiar de 5.5.9 a 5.6.31, quedaba activo el php-pgsql5 y no el php-pgsql5.6. Gracias por responder